# Correct syntax for views::istream or ranges::istream_view?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am trying to get into ranges::views.

The following demo program does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

namespace rng = std::ranges;

struct CompleteLine {    // Line Proxy for the input Iterator
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CompleteLine& cl) { std::getline(is, cl.completeLine); return is; }
    operator std::string() const { return completeLine; }  // cast operator
    std::string completeLine{};
};

std::istringstream iss{ R"(1 Line AAA
2 Line BBB
3 Line CCC)" };

int main() {
    for (const std::string& line : std::ranges::views::istream<CompleteLine>(iss)
        | std::views::transform([](std::string line) {
            std::ranges::transform(line, line.begin(),
                [](auto c) { return std::tolower(c); });
            return line;
            })) {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Error messages:

```
s\Armin\source\repos\Stackoverflow\Stackoverflow\stackoverflow.cpp(21,56): error C2039: 'istream': is not a member of 'std::ranges::views'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\ranges(4051): message : see declaration of 'std::ranges::views'
1>C:\Users\Armin\source\repos\Stackoverflow\Stackoverflow\stackoverflow.cpp(21,64): error C2275: 'CompleteLine': illegal use of this type as an expression
1>C:\Users\Armin\source\repos\Stackoverflow\Stackoverflow\stackoverflow.cpp(10): message : see declaration of 'CompleteLine'
1>C:\Users\Armin\source\repos\Stackoverflow\Stackoverflow\stackoverflow.cpp(21,5): error C2530: 'line': references must be initialized
1>C:\Users\Armin\source\repos\Stackoverflow\Stackoverflow\stackoverflow.cpp(21,34): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ':'
1>C:\Users\Armin\source\repos\Stackoverflow\Stackoverflow\stackoverflow.cpp(26,15): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ')'
1>Done building project "Stackoverflow.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

I am using "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.11.9" with "Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)"

---

Can somebody tell me the correct syntax for the above program to work please?

Comment: "*Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019*" This almost certainly does not support C++20. Or at least, not the ranges portion of it. Upgrade to newer versions of VC++ 2022.

Comment: There should be another tab with the full and complete build output, which can be copy-pasted as text. Please use it instead of the error list.

Comment: @NicolBolas. It does support ranges and I'm am using it. I cannot upgrade. I am on Windows 7 in a sandbox.

Comment: If version information at compiler explorer can be trusted, then this should compile with your MSVC version, but not 16.10 before it, see https://godbolt.org/z/MnrPv1593.

Comment: "_Can somebody tell me the correct syntax for the above program to work please?_": The syntax is correct. If it doesn't compile, then your compiler doesn't fully support C++20 ranges yet.

Comment: @AM `I am on Windows 7`. Even *Windows 7* isn't supported anymore....well, for two more weeks as of this comment. If you can't upgrade, consider finding another job or college or ....well if you're in high school you're SOL.

Comment: @user17732522 Thank you. So, it is a compiler issue. What a pity . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[P2432](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2432r1.pdf) (C++20 DR) allows us to construct a `basic_istream_view` object through customization point object `views::istream`.

But before that, we need to invoke the free function `istream_view(...)` to get a `basic_istream_view` object.

I suspect that the version of MSVC you are using has not implemented P2432, so the workaround is just to replace `views::istream` with `ranges::istream_view`

```
for (const std::string& line : std::ranges::istream_view<CompleteLine>(is)
                             | std::views::transform([](std::string line) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Astonishingly this works. So C++20  is only partly integrated in my VS version. This is wasting time of everybody . . .